# Returning value from async function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get back query data in JSON from my serverside code running on Node.JS

Here is my clientside AJAX request:

```
$(function() {
  var values = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/querySearch',
    type: 'post',
    data: values,
    success: function(msg){
      console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('failure');
    }
  });
});
```

My serserside code:

```
app.post('/querySearch', function(req, res) {
  var queryNumber = Number(req.body.queryNumber);
  if (queryNumber == 1){
    executeQuery1(res, sendQueryResults);
  }
  else if (queryNumber == 4){
    executeQuery4(res, sendQueryResults);
  }
  else if (queryNumber == 6){
    executeQuery6(res, sendQueryResults);
  }
  else if (queryNumber == 7){
    executeQuery7(res, sendQueryResults);
  }
});

function executeQuery1(res, callback) {
    var query = "" +
    'query string';
    service.oneshotSearch(query, {}, function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        alert("An error occurred with the search");
        return;
      }
    callback(res, results);
    });
  });

} 

function sendQueryResults(res, results) {
  res.json(JSON.stringify(results));
  res.end();
}
```

However, at the moment, my webpage won't even finish loading. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is happening? What is firebug/devtools saying when you make a request? Are there any server side errors?

Comment: Can you post code for sendQueryResults ?

Comment: The POST request isn't getting a response back. I've updated my post with more code above.

Comment: What are the `values`? What is supposed to happen with the response if `queryNumber` is something else than 1,4,6,7; what in case of an `err` in the search?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [res.end()](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding) after your have written your data in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one issue I see might be a problem is that [`res.json`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json) accepts an object and you're passing a string. Try:

```
res.json(results);
```

or just [`res.send`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send):

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
```

or I think this would work as well

```
res.send(results);
```

All three shouldh have the same result.